# Can we have a Cake Day icon, or similar?

Tags: feature-request

I don't know of any way - fun or otherwise, to be able to track the anniversaries of members joining the site.  Much like reddit has 'cake day', could we have site specific ones - on travel, even the travel 'pin' icon next to someone for their 'pin day', with perhaps 2 pins for 2 years, and so on.

It's nice to be able to see who has been around for a while, even if they don't necessarily have that much rep.

Comment: That is what the [`yearling` badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) is for.

Comment: "Member since" is in everyone's profile.

Comment: Cake day is stupid. *It's my cake day, here's an incredibly boring picture, give me upvotes!* *Upboat for cake day!* I really don't want to see such nonsense here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that doesn't appear on a question/answer/page on the day...

Comment: @MarkMayo: No, because we generally *focus on the content*, not the user. This is not a social site!

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting same kind of thing on MSO today, but then I thought, these kind of things are now welcome here. Guess I was right.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yet we have chat, talkative badges, hats at Christmas, meetups...

Comment: Chat (and the badges) is a different part of the site.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Chat, badges and meetups are entirely separate from the question and answer pages. Yes, they cater to a certain amount of social interaction between members of the community, but the *majority of visitors* come in without ever interacting with the community. They  are looking for an answer through google, find the answer and move on. We really don't want to impede on those users.

Comment: Really? Actual, legitimate close votes for "Evidently a horrible idea in some people's minds?"

Answer (score 12):

No, the Stack Exchange sites are about the *questions and answers*, not about the users.

This is not a social network. Users are really secondary to the primary goal of producing the best questions and answers.

We already have the [`yearling` badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) on the profile; we really don't want to encourage people to start congratulating people *on the question and answers pages*.

All 'social' features that do exist stand separate from the question and answer pages; chat is a separate site for example. Remember that the majority of visitors come in through Google searches, find their answer, and move on. We don't want to impede on those visitors.